# How to set default inputs for a program in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, input

**In Virtual studio code** , i dont want to give long input to my program everytime. Is there a way like in hackerearth to copy paste my input and the program will run on them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course. [Edit `launch.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference), specifically the [args](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_args) option of your target.

> ### Configure the target application
>
> #### args
>
> JSON array of command-line arguments to pass to the program when it is
>   launched. Example `["arg1", "arg2"]`.
>
> #### Example
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "C++ Launch",
>   "type": "cppdbg",
>   "request": "launch",
>   "program": "${workspaceRoot}/a.out",
>   "args": ["arg1", "arg2"],
>   "environment": [{ "name": "squid", "value": "clam" }],
>   "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
> }
> ```

Comment: This is my input. How should i write it in args list
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 5
2 6
4
5
6
3
4